# $ is not defined error while attaching the ajax html response?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, tinymce

**Below is the code snippet which is hitting the url on server and getting the html response.I can see
the response inside firefox debugger but it does not display in div tag.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: '',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        //in firefox debugger i can see complete html response inside data 
        $('#displayContent').html(data); // but here, it does not  
        // append the html inside div displayContent. Instead it makes 
        // the current page blank
    }
});​
```

**Looks like this is happening because of " $ is not defined " error(which i see in firefox debugger). This is happening because of inclusion of  below javascript file because if i comment out this file i dont get this error in firefox debugger and page gets displayed correctly.** But i can not comment out this file because i need it for text rich editor.
I am not getting why i am getting this error though same tiny_mce.js is working in other jsp files? Is there any relation of this with loading the html content thru ajax?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<s:url value="/script/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>'></script>
```

Comment: Which versing of tiny mce are you using? There is a version specifically for jQuery.

Comment: 3.2. To me it does not look like issue related to version as same js is included in other jsp files and its working

Comment: You should upgrade to 3.5 as there have been some bugfixes for jQuery compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a noConflict mode, which will allow you to use a different shortcut for calling jQuery functions and leave '$' for other frameworks.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Are you saying to include the js file something like this        <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.noConflict() </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<s:url value="/script/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>'></script>       But this not work either?

Comment: well, as per the documentation you should load the tinyMCE script first, then load the jquery script, then turn on noConclict. The order might make a big difference, or none, but I would try it as per the documentation before giving up on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all include jquery in your project and secondly include tinymce like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```